# How to set the string to date dataType in java

Tags: java, string, date, time, timestamp

I get date from the db, which contains date along with the timestamp, In the UI it displays both the date & timestanp, But I want to display only the date (yyyy-MM-dd). I have done the changes but i'm not able to set it right.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String startDate = dateFormat.format(dataObj.getReportStartDate());
//The above startDate will be of the format : 2012-11-08
```

I want the startDate which is in the String format to be set into Date datatype.

```
dataIndexObj.setReportStartDate(startDate);
// Here the setReportStartDate is of the type date(), I cannot change its type to string.
```

I tried with parse(startDate) too.. It did not work. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: What means "it did not work"? Is there a compile error, did it throw an exception at runtime, doesn't it do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I get error as Cannot convert from String to date. I want mm-dd-yyyy format to be set back to the variable whose data type is Date.

Comment: You can transform a java.util.Date to a formatted String, but you cannot tell a Date object how to format itself internally.

Answer (score 3):

Your question isn't terribly clear, because you've already got the data as a `Date` - the value you originally formatted.

If you mean that you'll be getting the data *back* from the UI as a `String`, and need to convert that, you just need to use `parse` instead of `format`:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
// TODO: Set the time zone as well...

Date date = dateFormat.parse(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you mean :

make 2 column in your db. first the type of string and the other date. so, when you need type of string you call a column of type string

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html). The first is poorly named and represents both a date *and* a time-of-day. The second is a bad hack of a class, extending from the first as a subclass, and pretending to hold only a date when in fact it does hold a time-of-day set to `00:00:00` UTC. Avoid these troublesome and poorly designed old classes. They are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

To get to such an object, convert your `java.util.Date` object by calling new methods added to the old date-time classes. We need an `Instant` along the way. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Perhaps you have a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) object from your database.

```
Instant instant = myTimestamp.toInstant();
```

Assign a time zone. A time zone is crucial because for any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

From that extract your `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate();  // A date-only value, truncating time-of-day and forgetting time zone.
```

To generate a string in your desired format, merely call `toString`. That format is a standard ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating String representations of date-time values.

```
String output = ld.toString();
```

Going the other direction.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2012-11-08" );
```